# How do I deploy a flask web application but still hide my source code?

Tags: javascript, flask, source-code-protection

I know I can make python executable but how do I hide the source code for Flask application which sends data to the frontend - html,javascript,css etc.. I am using a common deployment server - hence the need :)

Comment: Your Python code will not be visible, only the front-end code will be

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have your back-end logic displayed on any sort of public repository, and the company you use has a secure server network - nobody will see your code. That's why it's called "back-end" development :)

It's impossible for you to hide front-end code, like HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Comment: I want to hide the python code since I use a shared server